# Printer always prints one more page. How can I stop it?

Tags: printing

I have set up my Lexmark E120 printer successfully. However whenever I print (not always only 80% of the times) I get one more redundant page with the following text:

> ```
> L SET DENSITY=5
> @PJL SET RET=OFF
> @PJL SET ECONOMODE=ON
> @PJL SET DUPLEX=OFF
> ...
> ```

This is really annoying. How can I stop it?

Using Ubuntu latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a recommended driver (**hpijs-pcl5e**).

Try with the following: **ljet4**

It prints amazingly good, compared to the recommended (**hpijs-pcl5e**) :)

Comment: Thank you. This driver seems better than the old one! :-)